# summary isn't shown in single page

Tags: html, css, blogger, responsive, blogspot

I installed a free template on blogger, but the developer didn't answer me, so is there anybody can help me?
 I cannot see the summary in the page post, I can see it in the Home, but there isn’t in the single page. Everything that I wrote before the image it’s not shown. I actually change the single post’s HTML to show it, but I cannot do it for all the post (3000+), so I need to find a solution for all of them. How can I do?

home
http://www.consiglidimakeup.com/search?updated-max=2017-05-04T09:30:00%2B02:00&max-results=21&start=38&by-date=false
single post
http://www.consiglidimakeup.com/2017/05/recensione-cipria-compatta-nearly-nude-p2cosmetics-opinioni.html

thanks,
Silvia

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084915/display-summary-of-form-inputs check the above link

Comment: .post-entry p { display: block } maybe?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, but no it doesn't work :(